# Limit the number of rows in a SQL table with a specific value?

Tags: oracle

Essentially for our DBMS project we have to implement a patient table where each hospital (of three) can only handle 10 patients at a time.

```
INSERT INTO patient (name, treatment, disease, dateEntered, datedischarged, phoneNumber, primaryDoctorID,HospitalID)
VALUES (27,'Bruce','internal','ulcer','2022-01-09',null, '123-456-7878', 8,3);
```

What is the best method to limit the table by only allowing 10 patients with a null discharge date for each id? I've looked at Triggers and Functions, but the syntax seems above my skillset.

Comment: Trigger would do it.  There are many tutorials online.

Comment: As a side observation, what is the data type of columns dateEntered, datedischarged?  If properly designed, they should be DATE.  But you are inserting character strings.

Comment: it's a pretty superfluous feature for our intro class. i agree in a more robust version it'd be better to do Date.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table hospital (name varchar2(10), dateentered date, datedischarged date);

Table created.
```

A statement-level trigger; I set limit to 3 patients (didn't feel like creating at least 10 of them):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_limit
  2    before insert on hospital
  3  declare
  4    l_cnt number;
  5  begin
  6    select count(*) into l_cnt
  7      from hospital
  8      where datedischarged is null;
  9
 10    if l_cnt >= 3 then
 11       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Limit reached');
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.
```

Insert some sample rows:

```
SQL> insert into hospital (name, dateentered, datedischarged)
  2    select 'Little', sysdate - 10, null from dual union all
  3    select 'Foot'  , sysdate - 14, null from dual union all
  4    select 'Stack' , sysdate - 12, null from dual;

3 rows created.
```

OK, let's try to insert the 4th patient (3 are still in hospital):

```
SQL> insert into hospital (name, dateentered, datedischarged)
  2    select 'Sainz', sysdate, null from dual;
insert into hospital (name, dateentered, datedischarged)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Limit reached
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_LIMIT", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_LIMIT'
```

What if we discharge Sainz?

```
SQL> update hospital set datedischarged = sysdate where name = 'Stack';

1 row updated.

SQL> insert into hospital (name, dateentered, datedischarged)
  2    select 'Sainz', sysdate, null from dual;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Appreciate the guidance. this seems in the ballpark however getting a syntax error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare
      l_cnt number' at line 3"

Comment: MariaDB? Question is tagged with an **Oracle** tag, and code I posted *is* Oracle.